# Calculate voltage in circuit with capacitor

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-charging

I have a circuit where I have a capacitor (2F) in series with a resistor (1 Ohm) and a voltage source (v(0) = 10V). Now I am supposed to calculate v(t) for different t, like t=1s, t=2s and so on.

How do I do that? Is there a formula available for this? I need some ratio between the Farad of the Capacitor and the time it takes for it to load i guess...